# Assign id for each faces

Tags: python, opencv

Im using the following code to detect faces. After detection, Im drawing rectangle around the face. Then Im assigning id of the face which is the face number. If there are two faces,one face will have face id as 1 and the other one as 2.Following is my code.

```
detections = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(
    gray,
    scaleFactor=1.1,
    minNeighbors=5,
    minSize=(30, 30),
    flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
)

# Draw a rectangle around the faces
for (x, y, w, h) in detections:
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    face_no = detections.shape[0];

    cv2.putText(frame, str(face_no), (x, y - 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX,
                .7, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

But this code always returns the total number of faces. How can I get number for each face?

Comment: this way i want to differentiate individual faces so i can process each of them individually.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `detections.shape[0]` you are going to get the same value every time since there is no variable in there that changes based on the loop. What you could do is label the faces as you go using `enumerate` which will set `face_no` to the loop iteration number:

```py
for face_no, (x, y, w, h) in enumerate(detections):
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.putText(frame, str(face_no), (x, y - 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX,
                .7, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

Answer (score 1):

`detections` is a list of detected faces, and `len(detections)` should give you the number of faces. so, `detections[i]` is the ith face, making i the ID of that face.

if your loop is changed to

```
for i in range(o,len(detections):
    faceID = i
    currentFace = detections[i]
```

and so on, you can access them by ID.

Comment: Thx.. How do i get the x1,y1,x2,y2,w,h coordinates as in dlib?

Comment: With opencv's face detector, you get detections[i].x, detections[i].y, detections[i].w, and detections[i].h. If you want x2and y2, they can be calculated using the above four.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have calculated it. Is it possible to determine how long the face is being detected in terms of seconds? if so which function should I try? In objective c, we have NSTimer . What do we have in python to count the number of seconds?